# WCF Service 413 no matter which config item I change

Tags: json, rest, wcf, http-status-code-413

I have been trying to figure this out for days, to no avail. This happens both when I try to debug in Visual Studio using IIS Express and with my production web site deployed to a machine running IIS 7.5.

I have called the service from a Visual Studio Unit Test using `HttpWebRequest` and in Fiddler 4, same errors. So I don't think this is a WCF client configuration, as I am not using one.

No matter what I change in my configuration file, I am always getting this exception:

```
"Exception thrown: 'System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException' in 
System.ServiceModel.dll

Additional information: The maximum message size quota for incoming messages 
(65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the 
MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element."
```

The below Web.config that I am attaching is for an application that is not at the root of my server.

I am calling using the json endpoint using Ajax.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting the 64K limit, especially given that I have added all of the items to the `webHttpBinding` as below.

I have also changed the `httpRuntime` element by adding the `maxRequestLength` item, changed the request filtering, the security settings, and a whole slew of other things that didn't make a difference.

Notice also that I have turned on tracing. The `.svclog` file didn't tell me anything more.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
    <appSettings>
       <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
       <add key="FactoryType" value="Production"/>
       <add key="TravelRequestConnectionString" value="Data Source=ITLCS.benderson.com;Initial Catalog=TestTravelRequestSite;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXXX"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
       <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
       <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1"/>
       <membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
          <providers>
             <clear />
             <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
          </providers>
       </membership>
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
       <services>
          <service name="TravelRequestWebService.TravelRequestService">
             <endpoint
                 address="web"
                 binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 contract="TravelRequestWebService.ITravelRequestService" />
             <endpoint
                 address="json"
                 binding="webHttpBinding"
                 behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
                 contract="TravelRequestWebService.ITravelRequestService" />
             <endpoint
                 address=""
                 binding="basicHttpBinding"
                 contract="TravelRequestWebService.ITravelRequestService" />
          </service>
       </services>
       <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
             <behavior name="defaultBehavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
             </behavior>
             <behavior name="bigBehavior">
                <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="200"/>
             </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
             <behavior name="WebBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
             </behavior>
             <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
                <enableWebScript/>
             </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
       </behaviors>
       <bindings>
          <webHttpBinding>
             <binding name="webHttpBinding" allowCookies="true"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                      maxBufferSize="20000000">
             </binding>
          </webHttpBinding>
          <basicHttpBinding>
             <binding name="basicHttpBinding" allowCookies="true"
                      maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
                      maxBufferSize="20000000">
             </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
       </bindings>
       <protocolMapping>
          <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
       </protocolMapping>
       <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
       <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
       <!--
         To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
         Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
       -->
       <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.diagnostics>
       <sources>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                  switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                  propagateActivity="true">
             <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
             </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="CardSpace">
             <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
             </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.IO.Log">
             <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
             </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.Runtime.Serialization">
             <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
             </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.IdentityModel">
             <listeners>
                <add name="xml" />
             </listeners>
          </source>
       </sources>
       <sharedListeners>
          <add name="xml"
               type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
               initializeData="c:\log\Traces.svclog" />
       </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: If you are using a "Service Reference" generated client (svcutil or Visual Studio), make sure the client `system.serviceModel` configuration is in sync with your server-side configuration. Your server-side config looks valid. BTW: sa & password, really??

Comment: Hey Sixto, first off thanks for the catch, I'm editing out. Perhaps you posted this after I edited to add that I tested with both VS using HttpWebRequest and Fiddler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your config to this:

```
  <service name="TravelRequestWebService.TravelRequestService">
     <endpoint
         address="web"
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="TravelRequestWebService.ITravelRequestService" />
     <endpoint
         address="json"
         binding="webHttpBinding"
         behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior"
         bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"
         contract="TravelRequestWebService.ITravelRequestService" />
     <endpoint
         address=""
         binding="basicHttpBinding"
         contract="TravelRequestWebService.ITravelRequestService" />
  </service>
```

The clue was the 64K default limit for the message size in the error message. This implied your binding configuration was not being used by WCF. The fact the configurations are named the same as the endpoint bindings added confusion.

Comment: I'll be damned it worked. This is the last piece I needed, thank you SO much.